# Can you swap out a tile in a tiled TIFF without reading the whole image into memory?

Tags: image-processing, tiff, libtiff

I have a very large 1.2GB medical image that I would like to add annotations to. I have a tiled TIFF and I know the tile I would like to replace with a new equally sized tile/image, could I do so without reading the entire TIFF into memory and then re-writing the entire 1.2GB file to make such a small change?

In other words, can you swap out a portion of the TIFF without reading and writing the entire image each time?

Comment: In case the tiles are uncompressed, try to directly read/write the [TileByteCounts](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/tilebytecounts.html)[tileindex] bytes at [TileOffsets](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/tileoffsets.html)[tileindex].